# What is the time complexity of object spread operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I found that there are some QAs about spread operator time complexity but those are all for array.

Is the spread operator time complexity same for object?

```
a = { ...b }
```

What is the time complexity of the above statement if the key count of b is N?

is it O(N)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `O(n)`. Object spread iterates through all enumerable own properties and assigns them to a new object, and property assignment is an `O(1)` process. If there are N keys to iterate through, there are around N such operations to perform.

That said, this here will not be a bottleneck in 99.9% of actual code, so it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Is there any faster way to copy object?

Comment: The only way I could think of would be to do `Object.create(originalObj)`. It's not exactly a copy - it'll be the internal prototype. Might suit your purposes - but speed is **not** an issue to remotely worry about in this situation. Don't bother, IMO.

Comment: @True [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: "this here will not be a bottleneck in 99.9% of actual code", can you explain what do you mean by this?

Comment: @netotz "What is slowing an application down?" The vast majority of the time, a random piece of code from the application is *not* the bottleneck. If an app is running too slowly, often there will be *one* or *two* or *three* or so sections of code that are causing issues - sections which comprise only 1% of the actual codebase. A line that has `Object.assign` in it is quite unlikely to be causing performance problems - if there's an issue, it's probably elsewhere.

Comment: A good general approach is not to worry about speed until you run a performance test and can identify sections causing slowness when the app is running normally. Don't try to optimize before then, because micro-optimizations for non-bottlenecks make code more difficult to understand. Strive for clean, readable code first, and only consider performance once there's an actual issue to fix.